# How to set a default password for root in yocto fido

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto

*I have read the previous answers like below

```
INHERIT += "extrausers"  
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "usermod -P p@ssw0rd root;"
```

if I add the above line in my `local.conf` I cannot create a patch.

So I need guidance to set a default password to `root`. I found a path in poky below ,which file I need to change. and what can I change.

`/home/..../sources/poky/meta/recipes-extended/shadow*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is not a good idea to modify the default meta files. To add users you can modify your image recipe and simply add:

```
inherit extrausers
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS += "usermod -P p@ssw0rd root;"
```

The location of your image recipe depends on your setup, it will probably be in your custom meta.

Comment: I have added in my recipe image but its not working. Is there any other way.

Comment: Did you remove the debug-tweaks package from your image? It forces the password to be empty.

Comment: Dear Pierreolivier Thanks for your help i have added thosetwo lines in my meta/conf/layer.conf then its working fine. for future use please tell me  in what dir can i find the debug-tweaks.

Comment: local.conf is the wrong place to put that "code. What if you create a new workbuild? You must modify the local.conf from scratch...

Answer (score 0):

I used to modify shadow file manually

```
ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND += "change_root_psw;"
change_root_psw() {
   sed 's%^root:[^:]*:%root:<encrypted_password_goes_here>:%' \
       < ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/etc/shadow \
       > ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/etc/shadow.new;
   mv ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/etc/shadow.new ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/etc/shadow ;
}
```

Encrypted password can be retrieved directly from shadow file.

Comment: Dear Lps thanks, please tell me which file i need to add the above lines.

Comment: The main recipe you use to build you image, eg. `core-image-minimal.bb`